# How to see all databases in phpMyAdmin as phpmyadmin user?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been using MySQL successfully using the command line, and have created various databases (mostly for CMS).

I decided to try using `phpMyAdmin` which I saw mentioned in a book on Joomla!.

But when I click on Databases, I only see information_schema, phpMyAdmin, and test.

I want to be able to administer all of my databases (presumably giving appropriate credentials). Probably related is the fact that if I log into mysql as the `phpmyadmin` user and do a show databases; query, I see only those three databases.

Do I need some sort of a grant involving the `show_db_priv` (granting to the `phpmyadmin` user)? If that's it, what is the exact syntax for doing that? When I do a show grants for this user, I can see that `show_db_priv` is not one of them.

Comment: Simply use your mysql root credentials (securely though) for PHPMyAdmin Configuration and it will show all your databases

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work. But now I'm wondering what the point of the separate phpmyadmin user is.

Answer (score 6):

Login as MySQL root user in phpMyAdmin. If you're not able to login as root in-spite of providing correct password, then make sure that you have this line in your phpMyAdmin's config.inc.php and is set to true.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] =     true;
```

If you've not assigned password to MySQL root account, then default password is blank. In that case check that AllowNoPassword is set to true in phpMyAdmin's config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answer is relevant, as I am using phpMyAdmin as part of WAMP on a single site machine. Still, it might help someone else running into the problem of phpMyAdmin not displaying existing databases.

After installing WAMP on a new machine (with phpMyAdmin 4.0.4), and using a php script of mine to create some databases, phpMyAdmin would only show the information_schema and test databases.

When I ran mysql from a command prompt, the databases were there, so wtf??

After some experimenting I discovered that adding the following line cured the problem:

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

Note that the config.inc.php already had

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = false;
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mypwd';

- Note: The  auth_type parameter is discussed in http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/auth_types,
  but I don't see any comment on failure to show user created databases.
- More details:
  Without the auth_type line, a SHOW GRANTS (from phpMyAdmin) yields:

  > GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*CF74EB88D030BC86A14151B7CE22C8808A19AA4B'
- With the auth_type line, SHOW GRANTS yields:

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*CF74EB88D030BC86A14151B7CE22C8808A19AA4B' WITH GRANT OPTION
>
> GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Those two lines will grant **all** privileges for the user `phpmyadmin`. You might need to restart mysql service.

If you didn't have a user named `phpmyadmin` in the first place, you can create it with the following:

`CREATE USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_secret_password';`

This answer definitely exists somewhere else, but I can't find it to give it credit.